# Обработка исключения EF Core

Tags: база-данных, asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Приложение на ASP.NET Core MVC. Помогите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать.
Есть две таблицы. Связь описана следующим образом:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroup>()
            .HasOne(ug => ug.Group)
            .WithMany(g => g.UserGroups)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .HasForeignKey(ug => ug.GroupId);
```

т. е. запретил удаление, если есть связанные записи. Как правильно обработать исключение, которое возникает при попытке удаления записей "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint"? Или в контроллере перед самим удалением, проверить имеются ли связанные записи ?